# How to ellipsize many TextView's as it would be one TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I wont to create layout like:

```
| textview1  Longtextview2  TextView7 |
| textview4  Textview5  TextView6     |
| textVie6 ...                        |
```

and so on.

I tried Linear, Table and Relative layouts but I wasn't able to get exactly this effect for more than 2 lines. I tried ellipsize TextView's, but I'm not sure if it can works with many TextViews together, and nested TextView's aren't allowed.

What layout and options should I use to get this effect?

The TextView's should behave like words in ellipsized TextView.

PS. I could use something else, but I will have to be able get event like clicking on a particular word. Maybe modified EditText would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single TextView can have separate clickable words, different text formatting, style etc. Check out [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) and [styling resources doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)

Comment: But I would be forced to add links to all my words, and still can't determinate where I exactly clicked... It's a not good solution.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Do you need to know exact pixels of where you clicked, or which word? You can set a regex pattern so that every separate word, character, [bracketed phrase] etc is its own clickable area of text that will trigger its own event.

Comment: I'm afraid clicking on Linkify trigger won't give me the word's position in text so i could edit it. I could be wrong, if yes, correct me.

Comment: Not without some working around. If you want to edit the text, why didn't you go straight for an EditText rather than multiple TextViews?